# Add rows(<tr>) to table(<table>)?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to add rows to a table dynamically inside a for loop.
 User selects 1,2,3 or 4 from a radio button list and the corresponding number of rows get added to the table. The table would initially have no rows at all.

**Edit:**

I want to add rows equal to selected item's value with a loop probably (maybe there is some other way) and add months to the current date  with a serial no.

Here is my Fiddle [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XWFHA/1/)

I need to put the dates inside labels so I later fetch them server side through javascript or some other method.

Comment: please post sample code you have in jsfiddle.net and then we'll help you with it.

Comment: @damien , you mean regular talbe??

Comment: @gov yep, I mean regular table. @corroded doing it in some minutes...

Comment: A SQL table or the HTML DOM table?

Comment: Can you also describe how many columns the table should have and whether it should have a header row? Also, is there any content that this is likely to have? Surely simply populating cells alone is not likely to be very useful?

Comment: Sorry Mitch, please check my sample code. Damien

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure.

```
var num = parseInt($('.radio-button-list:selected').val());
for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    var row = $('<tr></tr>');

    // todo: build your table row appropriately here
    $('#my-table').append(row);
}
```

Comment: Thanks DarkWing, please check my example. Also it wont add anything if I don't put a header <tr> in the table. Isn't there any way to add rows to an table empty initially ?

Comment: My question for your scenario: at what point in time will those empty table rows be created? Are they going to remain empty forever?

Comment: The page will load with no rows initialy. User may add or delete all rows to the table